# Returns the year for each month by period - nested case statements

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

```
def return_year_by_month_and_period(month)
pw = self.property_water.first().billing_increment
case pw
  when "12"
    self.property_water.where(period: month).first().year
  when "6"
    case month
      when 1, 2
        self.property_water.where(period: 1).first().year
      when 3, 4
        self.property_water.where(period: 2).first().year
      when 5, 6
        self.property_water.where(period: 3).first().year
      when 7, 8
        self.property_water.where(period: 4).first().year
      when 9, 10
        self.property_water.where(period: 5).first().year
      else
        self.property_water.where(period: 6).first().year
    end
  when "4"
    case month
      when 1, 2, 3
        self.property_water.where(period: 1).first().year
      when 4, 5, 6
        self.property_water.where(period: 2).first().year
      when 7, 8, 9
        self.property_water.where(period: 3).first().year
      else
        self.property_water.where(period: 4).first().year
    end
  when "2"
    case month
      when 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        self.property_water.where(period: 1).first().year
      else
        self.property_water.where(period: 2).first().year
    end
  else
    self.property_water.first().year
end
end
```

"Period" in the text above is one of months, bi-monthly, quarterly, semi-annually or annually.

For each of the 12 months in the calendar year, we want to associate a year (e.g. 2015) with the month depending on what year is associated with the period.

First let me say - I think the database modeling for this particular thing is horribly FUBAR.  I inherited the project - and re-making the database is on the roadmap, but not the immediate need.

So in the example above, if I had a period of 2 (bi-monthly) - I would only have 6 records in the property_waters table.  But I still have 12 months, so I need to say "the 1st period is Jan and Feb" and this logic has to carry.  The property_waters table does NOT have a 'month' column, meaning my two attributes are period and year.  From the period, I can determine which months belong in which group, and return the year of the period.

The code works - but even after I wrote it I knew I could do better.  I just can't see it, so please help me learn a better way to do this.

EDIT:
Billing increment for every record is always the same integer as the period. So if we have 6 records for billing period of bi-monthly, all 6 records have billing_increment = 6.

Ridiculous I know. We can just count the records to return this same thing...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `billing_increment` is always an integer that is a factor of 12, the code should be entirely formulaic.

```
def return_year_by_month_and_period(month)
  period_len = property_water.first.billing_increment.to_i
  if 12 % period_len != 0
    # TODO: decide what the appropriate behavior should be
    self.property_water.first.year
  else
    nth_period = (month - 1) / period_len + 1
    property_water.where(period: nth_period).first.year
  end
end
```

I've incorporated additional suggestions from @tokland:

1. In Ruby it's not idiomatic to write `self.`, nor parens on calls without arguments.
2. Write the second case in an `else`. Full conditional branches are easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, month is not a factor of 12. Month is an integer 1-12 representing Jan-Dec. billing period would be a factor of 12: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12 are possible values. The count of records in the table match the billing period. If we get 6 bills per year, we have 6 records in our table.

Comment: Oops, I misspoke.

Comment: Wrote a lot more but my phone hung up and it was all erased. I apologize. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you can eliminate the inner `case` statements using simple math to calculate the right period:

```
case pw
  when "12"
    self.property_water.where(period: month).first().year
  when "6"
    self.property_water.where(period: (month - 1) / 2 + 1).first().year
  when "4"
    self.property_water.where(period: (month - 1) / 3 + 1).first().year
  when "2"
    self.property_water.where(period: (month - 1) / 6 + 1).first().year
  else
    self.property_water.first().year
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider writing this as follows:

First obtain the number of months per billing period:

```
months_per_billing_period = property_water.first().billing_increment
```

and then for any `month` (`1-12`), compute:

```
return_year_by_month_and_period(months_per_billing_period, month)
```

where:

```
def return_year_by_month_and_period(months_per_billing_period, month)
  property_water.where(month_to_period(months_per_billing_period,
    month)).first().year
end

def month_to_period(months_per_billing_period, month)
  (month.to_f / months_per_billing_period).ceil.to_i
end
```

A few points:

- I don't believe you need `self.` anywhere.
- For 12 months per billing period, don't you want `property_water.where(period: 1).first().year`, as there is only one period per year in that case?
- The method `return_year_by_month_and_period` should have a more descriptive name.